# React component: Simulate standard HTML <input/> API

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a component with an API like any standard input element, meaning I want to use it like this: `<CustomInput value={this.state.custom_input_state} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Here is what I have so far, but I have no idea how to

- Make the custom components value changeable from the parent component
  after it has been constructed
- Make the parent's onChange handler function recieve a change event when the
  custom component's value changes

Here is my test setup:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            foo: 0
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert(this.state.foo);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState({foo: this.state.foo + 1});    
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div onClick={this.increment}>Increment from parent</div>
                <CustomInput name="foo" value={this.state.foo} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        )
    }
}


class CustomInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value,
        };
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1});    
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div onClick={this.increment}>Increment self</div>
                <input name={this.props.name} value={this.state.value}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass all the CustomInput props to the input element. In CustomInput component actually it not recieving the onChange event.

Pass the prop onChange event to input element

Form Component

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      foo: 'React'
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Custominput name="foo" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.foo} />
        </form>
        {this.state.foo}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CustomInput Component

```
export default class CustomInput extends React.Component{


  render(){
    return(
        <input {...this.props} />
    )
  }
}
```

demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dqsc1z)